# Does the Google LocationServices need internet?

Tags: android, api, google-api, offlineapps, google-location-services

When you're offline (no wifi nor mobile) does the Google Location Services Api work ? and if it does, does it just return the last known location (the last time the user was online) or does it return the real curent location ?

Answer (score 0):

no google location service don t need internet service cuz there is a chip in your phone make the google location service determine your location :) ;)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me where you read this information because I need to refer to it in my presentation (I need to refer to a real article in order to justify my use of google api for location)